# Polynomial Space Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be contained in $P_n([-5,5])$ such that

$S=\{f(x) \in P_n[-5,5]$ | $f'(-1)=0, f''(1)=0\}$

Check if S is a subspace of $P_n(-5,5)$

I have absolutely no idea how to go about this, (topic is in regards to $L_p$ norms and inner products.

I know we are supposed to check the three conditions which are 0 is part of S, closed under addition and closed under scalar multiplication, but how would I pick stuff to satisfy the f'(-1)=0 and f'(1)=0?

Since it's saying $P_n$ is the polynomial space from [-5,5] does that mean it's just that the space is a restriction portion of when the polynomial space is just the reals ie $P_1$?

Comment: Just use the definition of **subspace** . Clearly $0\in S$. If $f,g\in S$ then $h'(-1)=f'(-1)+g'(-1)=h''(1)=0$ where $h=f+g$, so $h\in S$. Can you finish now?

Comment: I think I get it now, this would pass the scalar multiplication test also as $r*f'(-1) = r*0 = 0$ and $r*f''(1)=r*0 = 0$which is good enough to show it's closed under scalar multiplication. Therefore this is a subspace,

Comment: Yes! Good for you

Comment: thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 1):

The space $P_n([-5,5])$ is the space of polynomial of degree less or equal than $n$ with domain $[-5,5]$.

Let $f$, $g\in S$. By definition of $S$, we know that $f'(-1)=0$, $f''(1)=0$, $g'(-1)=0$ and $g''(1)=0$, so
$$(f+g)'(-1)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad (f+g)''(1)=0,$$
hence $f+g\in S$.